# How to add texts on creation of text file using C# windows application?

Tags: c#

I have created a C# windows application project.. Here i need to add  some texts in a new text file and i should create that file on button click.. So When i click the button, i should create a text file and that should have the texts which i have given using the controls.. But my problem is when i click the button, it create new file and when writing the texts in file, it has faced some problem that " **The process cannot access the file 'D:\MyWork\DemoEpub\98989.txt' because it is being used by another process.** " I have given the code below.. Please help me to free from this error

```
        private void Create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            FileStream fs = null;
            string fileLoc = @"D:\MyWork\DemoEpub\" + textBox1.Text + ".txt";
            if (!File.Exists(fileLoc))
            {
                using (fs = File.Create(fileLoc))
                {
                    if (File.Exists(fileLoc))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileLoc))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                sw.Write("<START>\n<TITLE>" + textBox1.Text + "</TITLE>\n<BODY>\n<P>PAGE " + textBox2.Text + "</P>\n<P>\n" + richTextBox1.Text + "</P>\n</BODY>\n<END>");
                            }
                            catch(System.IO.IOException exp)
                            {
                                sw.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File.Create creates and opens the file already. It returns a Stream object which keeps the file open **and locked** until this Stream object is being closed/disposed.

Using the *StreamReader* constructor with a **string** path will make *StreamReader* trying to open the file again, which will fail for the reasons mentioned above.

To utilize the already Stream object *fs* (which has the file already open and locked), simply pass it to the constructor of *StreamReader*:

```
    string fileLoc = @"D:\MyWork\DemoEpub\" + textBox1.Text + ".txt";
    if (!File.Exists(fileLoc))
    {
        using (Stream fs = File.Create(fileLoc))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
           ...
        }
    }
```

Also note that you don't need to do a second *File.Exists()* check after you obtained *fs*. Obtaining a valid Stream object from *File.Create()* means that the file has been successfully created. If the file could not be created, *File.Create()* would throw an exception instead.

Another approach is to use the *StreamWriter* directly with the given string path (and not creating a *Stream* object separately):

```
    string fileLoc = @"D:\MyWork\DemoEpub\" + textBox1.Text + ".txt";
    if (!File.Exists(fileLoc))
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileLoc))
        {
           ...
        }
    }
```

Finally, as a side note i want to point that you don't need to explicitly close the StreamReader or Stream object in an exception handler if you use the **using** statement. *using* will take care of disposing (which includes closing) the StreamReader or Stream object provided as its arguments when the program leaves the scope of the *using* statement. More details regarding *using* can be found in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Comment: @user3336631 Please mark this answer as the solution.

Comment: @user3336631, yes you should vote also for ToughCoder :)

Comment: Just FYI, this will dispose the filestream twice.  Shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @alejosoft I am new to Stack Overflow.. So Can you guide me that how to mark this answer as a solution and also how to give likes to your solution :)

Comment: @BenVoigt, it is not a problem, fortunately. If this would not be possible, then you would need to explicitly handle exceptions thrown by the StreamWriter constructor, and do conditional manual disposing of the Stream object -- which would in turn make "using" somewhat useless for streams, and source code less readable.

Comment: @user3336631, regarding alejosoft's comment, i would take a slow approach of accepting an answer. Take your time before you make a decision. Generally, [look here how accepting an answer works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) - especially with regard to the advices given in and underneath the section titled "Which answer should I choose?".

Answer (score 0):

The using statements in the example open and prepare the files. At the end of the statements they close and dispose of the resources. If your program does lots of writes, it will manage system resources correctly if you use using.

In this example StreamWriter creates the file for you and closes the file so you don't need to write a close function. Catch is to log your errors.

```
    private void Create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string fileLoc = @"D:\MyWork\DemoEpub\" + textBox1.Text + ".txt";
       if (!File.Exists(fileLoc))
       {
          using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileLoc))
          {
                    try
                    {
                        sw.Write("<START>\n<TITLE>" + textBox1.Text + "</TITLE>\n<BODY>\n<P>PAGE " + textBox2.Text + "</P>\n<P>\n" + richTextBox1.Text + "</P>\n</BODY>\n<END>");
                    }
                    catch(System.IO.IOException exp)
                    {
                        //Catch your error here.
                    }
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unnecessary cast, and also could use some explanation why you're using a disposable object without a `using` block for it (correct in this case, but needs explanation)